# UIPageViewController doesn't load the content

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

Hi this is my first attempt with UIPageViewController.  I followed [this](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) tutorial and for some reason the PageContentViewController never loads.  I know I am probably missing something really silly so I would appreciate a fresh set of eyes.

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard:

[image]

This is the class that acts as the PageViewController's datasource

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Pregrancy
//
//  Created by Andreas Kaitis on 24/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Andreas Kaitis. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PageContentViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () 

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _pageImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:  @"week1", @"week2", @"week3", @"week4",
                                                    @"week5", @"week6", @"week7", @"week8",
                                                    @"week9", @"week10",@"week11",@"week12",
                                                    @"week13",@"week14",@"week15",@"week16",
                                                    @"week17",@"week18",@"week19",@"week20",
                                                    @"week21",@"week22",@"week23",@"week24",
                                                    @"week25",@"week26",@"week27",@"week28",
                                                    @"week29",@"week30",@"week31",@"week32",
                                                    @"week37",@"week38",@"week39",@"week40", nil];

    _pageTitles = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:  @"Month 1", @"Month 1", @"Month 1", @"Month 1",
                                                    @"Month 2", @"Month 2", @"Month 2", @"Month 2",
                                                    @"Month 3", @"Month 3", @"Month 3", @"Month 3",
                                                    @"Month 4", @"Month 4", @"Month 4", @"Month 4",
                                                    @"Month 5", @"Month 5", @"Month 5", @"Month 5",
                                                    @"Month 6", @"Month 6", @"Month 6", @"Month 6",
                                                    @"Month 7", @"Month 7", @"Month 7", @"Month 7",
                                                    @"Month 8", @"Month 8", @"Month 8", @"Month 8",
                                                    @"Month 9", @"Month 9", @"Month 9", @"Month 9",nil];

    _pageSubtitles = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"week1", @"week2", @"week3", @"week4",
                                                    @"week5", @"week6", @"week7", @"week8",
                                                    @"week9", @"week10", @"week11", @"week12",
                                                    @"week13", @"week14", @"week15", @"week16",
                                                    @"week17", @"week18", @"week19", @"week20",
                                                    @"week21", @"week22", @"week23", @"week24",
                                                    @"week25", @"week26", @"week27", @"week28",
                                                    @"week29", @"week30", @"week31", @"week32",
                                                    @"week33", @"week34", @"week35", @"week36",nil];

    _pageBodyText = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"week1", @"week2", @"week3", @"week4",
                                                    @"week5", @"week6", @"week7", @"week8",
                                                    @"week9", @"week10", @"week11", @"week12",
                                                    @"week13", @"week14", @"week15", @"week16",
                                                    @"week17", @"week18", @"week19", @"week20",
                                                    @"week21", @"week22", @"week23", @"week24",
                                                    @"week25", @"week26", @"week27", @"week28",
                                                    @"week29", @"week30", @"week31", @"week32",
                                                    @"week33", @"week34", @"week35", @"week36",nil];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.subtitleText = self.pageSubtitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.bodyText = self.pageBodyText[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}


@end
```

and the PageContentViewController

```
#import "PageContentViewController.h"

@interface PageContentViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource>

@end

@implementation PageContentViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageFile];
    self.monthLabel.text = self.titleText;
    self.weekLabel.text = self.subtitleText;
    self.bodyTextLabel.text = self.bodyText;

    self.monthVisualEffectView.hidden = YES;
    self.weekVisualEffectView.hidden = YES;


    self.months = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Month 1",@"Month 2",@"Month 3",@"Month 4",@"Month 5",@"Month 6",@"Month 7",@"Month 8",@"Month 9", nil];

    self.weeks = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:  @"week 1", @"week 2",   @"week 3",  @"week 4",
                                                   @"week 5", @"week 6",   @"week 7",  @"week 8",
                                                   @"week 9", @"week 10",  @"week 11", @"week 12",
                                                   @"week 13", @"week 14", @"week 15", @"week 16",
                                                   @"week 17", @"week 18", @"week 19", @"week 20",
                                                   @"week 21", @"week 22", @"week 23", @"week 24",
                                                   @"week 25", @"week 26", @"week 27", @"week 28",
                                                   @"week 29", @"week 30", @"week 31", @"week 32",
                                                   @"week 33", @"week 34", @"week 35", @"week 36",nil];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should do some troubleshooting by adding logs in several places to try to narrow down the problem. Are the data source methods ever called? Does PageContentViewController's viewDidLoad method get called?

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for your time. The PageContentViewController's viewDidLoad gets called but the datasource methods don't get called.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I copied your code, and it worked for me, so I'm not sure what's wrong. Have you put a log in the data source methods to make sure they're not being called? Are you not seeing even the first page of the content controller?

Comment: ok so the datasource methods get called and I think my problem is with the pageImages array.  The images are stored in the images.xcassets as sets.  From  Apples docs it should be as simple as calling the imageNamed method of UIImage with the name of the set, which I am doing...this is driving me crazy...

Comment: In PageContentViewController, what does a log of [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageFile] show?

Comment: it shows: <UIImage: 0x7b9ca8c0>

Comment: Ok, so it seems your pageImages array is working then. How about self.imageView, is it non-nil?

Comment: How can I check if its non-nil? sorry but i am new at this

Comment: Just log it. NSLog(@"%@",self.imageView). The log should be inside viewDidLoad of PageContentViewController.

Comment: Result: <UIImageView: 0x7a9757e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7a9739f0>>

Comment: Well, you're not going to see an image if the frame of the image view is zero. You need to add the proper constraints to it in the storyboard.

Comment: I am not using auto layout but I have all the constraints in the auto resizing field active. I added a screenshot of the constraints in IB

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that the frame will log correctly in viewDidLoad. Implement viewDidAppear and log self.imageView there to see if it has a valid frame.

Comment: it gives the same log in viewDidAppear